# Django update slug field

Tags: django, models, slug

i have a problem, my model was without slug field, so now i need to add a slug field, but my models is full of data, im using django evolution and was cool added the new slug field...but how ill update the slug fiel with the data form the title field at once?

Thanks

Comment: Yes Ignacio, im trying that, but i have problem with environment variable with the shell

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

http://south.aeracode.org/

It will allow you to modify your schema but keep your data intact.